# Exploit "free whitespace"

Tags: code-golf, whitespace

Suppose a codegolf challenge doesn't count whitespace in the length of your program.  Cheat this system by encoding your script into whitespace, and golf a script which decodes and executes embedded whitespace.

**Example**

My solution to [JBernardo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2212/jbernardo)'s [Meta Golf Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3203/2180) was to encode Sage (or Python) code into whitespace, and golf the decoder.

```
s = ' '
for c in '<lots of whitespace>'.split(s):
    s+=chr(len(c))
exec s
```

The encoding is to take a script, prepend a newline, and for each character `c` in the script, output `ord(c)` tabs followed by a space.  Prepending a newline is necessary since I'm using Python and I start the script `s` with a space.

**Scoring**

A complete solution contains a description of the encoding you use (if it's complicated, provide a script), and a 'decode-and-execute' script.  Your score is the number of non-whitespace characters in the decode-and-execute script.

**Whitespace (the language) is forbidden**

Moreover, any language which has a complete set of operators which only use whitespace characters is not allowed: I'll accept the lowest nonzero score.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Golfscript, 12 chars

String delimited by `'` goes before these 10 chars:

```
n/{,}%''+~
```

Each line is decoded into one character, whose ASCII (probably Unicode, in fact) value is the length of the line.

Unfortunately if I try pasting my Hello World example, Markdown removes the extra spaces, even in a `<pre>` block.

Comment: Since whitespace at the beginning of a program is always non-functional, `.n/{,}%+~` would work as well.

Answer (score 9):

### CPAN, 16

```
use Acme::Bleach;
```

CPAN has it all.  Or at least, [just the right module.](https://metacpan.org/module/Acme%3a%3aBleach)

Comment: I call cheat on this, that is a complete set of operators that is nothing but whitespace

Comment: This is not a cheat.  It's cheap, but acceptable.

Comment: This program does nothing. None of the WS is there. BOOOOOO!!!! Please repost this with a program that does something useful here. Keep the Acme::Bleach use, but take advantage of it.

Comment: @trinithis: as do none of the other programs presented here. Why pick specifically on this one?

Comment: I noticed it and it stands out as a what does this do, it only looks like it imports.

Comment: Well, surprisingly enough, that's all that's needed.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I thought of when I saw this challenge.  I argue it isn't cheating because, it DOES have non-whitespace characters and, the entire spirit of the challenge is to encode everything but a decoder stub.  This decoder stub just happens to have been built several decades ago ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 29

```
$_="";s/     */chr length $&/ge;eval
```

Inside that `s///` are a tab then a space.  The encoding is an ultra-basic encode with spaces, precede with tabs.

Try this one on the command line:

```
$ tr ST ' \t' <<< '$_="TSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"; s/TS*/chr length $&/ge; eval' | perl
```

<s>Edit: well, lol, I can't find a proper way to copy-paste the tab/space mix.  Believe me, it works at home :)</s>
Update: there, there, encoded with `tr`

Comment: you can put tabs in with `\t` and we'll believe it works with whitespace...

Comment: @boothby: oh, better than that, I can have the `\t` interpreted by the shell and actually have the damn thing work demonstrably.  Doing that in a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript

Replace `\t` with a tab to get the posted character count.

#### Standard (64 characters)

```
eval(eval("'<code here>'".replace(/\t */g,function(s){return"\\"+s.length})))
```

#### [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) (49 characters)

```
eval(eval("'<code here>'".replace(/\t */g,(s)=>"\\"+s.length)))
```

#### Encoder program for both

```
for(var i = 0, si = prompt("Enter the code."), so = ""; i < si.length; ++i) so += '\t' + Array(+si.charCodeAt(i).toString(8)).join(' '); prompt("Here is the result.", so);
```

Comment: Replace `(s)=>...` in the arrow function to `s=>...` to save two bytes

Comment: Keep spaces between any two char and at worst use jsfuck to make it work(and better use `" t " [ 1 ]` to mean "t")

Comment: 44B ```eval("".replace(/ +/g,s=>' []+!()'[s.length]))```

Answer (score 2):

### C (99 characters)

```
main(c, p)
{
    char *s = "<code here>";
    for (p = popen("cc -xc -oa -", "w"); *s;)
        *s++ - 9 ? c -= putc(c, p) : ++c;
    execl("a", pclose(p));
}
```

Tested only with (and perhaps only works with) GCC.

Corresponding encoder program (manually remove the first character from its output):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        while (c--) putchar(9);
        putchar(32);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Yabasic (88 characters)

```
a$ = "<code here>"
for a = 1 to len(a$)
    if mid$(a$, a) < " " then b = b + 1
    else b$ = b$ + chr$(b) : b = 0
    endif
next
compile(b$)
a()
```

Use the same encoder program as for my C solution, but do not remove the first character. Your original code must be in the form of a subroutine `a()`, for example:

```
sub a():?"hello, world":end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### D (101 chars)

```
import std.algorithm;mixin((){char[]r;foreach(c;splitter("<lots of whitspace>"," "))r~=cast(char)c.length;return r;}());
```

same encoding as in the question (no need for the newline)

Comment: The point of this is that whitespace is free.  I count 98 characters.  Feel free to write readable code!

Answer (score 1):

### Bash (builtins only, 44 characters)

```
IFS=
eval `while read a
do printf '\'${#a}
done<<a
<code here>
a`
```

Corresponding encoder script:

```
od -b | cut -b9- | tr ' ' '\n' | while read a
do
    for (( b = 0; b < $((10#$a)); ++b ))
    do
        echo -n ' '
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: Very nice.  I consider myself a bit of a Bash hacker, and I had to `man` up a bit to grok this.

Answer (score 1):

## K5, 12 bytes

```
.`c$-':&9=" "
```

Execute (`.`) the string formed from the ascii values (`` `c$ ``) given by the difference between each pair (`-':`) of the indices where (`&`) the input is a tab (`9=" "`).

Input is a string of tab- and non-tab characters, and the character values are encoded in the number of non-tabs (spaces or newlines) between each tab. An example encoder:

```
" ",/{(x#" "),"\t"}'-1+
```

Perform a running join beginning with a space over (`" ",/`) x spaces (`x#" "`) joined with a tab (`,"\t"`) where X is each of (`{...}'`) one minus the character values of the input string (`-1+`).

In action:

```
  enc: " ",/{(x#" "),"\t"}'-1+
  dec: .`c$-':&9=

  enc "2+3"
"                                                  \t                                          \t                                                  \t"
  dec enc "2+3"
5
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 43

Very straightforward, encoding is putting x spaces per line, where x is the ascii value of the char, decoding is reverse.

The following script is just a unary to ASCII converter and works even when things other than spaces are free:

```
eval("".split("\n").map{|x|x.length.chr}.join)
```

Just replace the empty string with the program that pleases you.

The thing in a more reusable format:

```
from_space = lambda {|text| text.split("\n").map{|x| x.length.chr}.join}
to_space = lambda {|text| text.chars.map{|x| " " * x.ord}.join("\n")}

p from_space [ to_space [ "abc" ] ] #=> "abc"
```