# Determine if a number is divisible by 13 (without using 13 itself)

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is to create a function or a program that outputs "yes" if a given number is divisible by 13 and outputs "no" if it isn't.

**Rules:**
 - You're not allowed to use the number 13 anywhere.
 - No cop-out synonyms for 13 either (like using 15 - 2).
 - Bonus points will be awarded for not using modulus, additional bonus for not using division.

**Scoring:**
 - Your score will be the number of bytes in your code (whitespace *not* included) multiplied by your bonus.
 - If you didn't use modulus, that bonus is 0.90; if you didn't use division, that bonus is 0.90.
 - If you didn't use either, that bonus is 0.80.
 - The lower your score, the better.

The input will always be an integer greater than 0 and less than 2^32.
Your output should be a simple "yes" or "no".

**Clarifications:**
 - Using some roundabout method of generating the number 13 for use is acceptable.  Simple arithmetic synonyms like (10 + 3) are not allowed.
 - The function or program must *literally output* "yes" or "no" for if the given number is divisible by 13.
 - As always, clever solutions are recommended, but not required.

Comment: is 'true' or 'false' a valid output?

Comment: JavaScript (27 chars) `function f(n){return "yes"}`. This will return 'yes' for all the numbers that can be divided by 13

Comment: "(whitespace not included)" always have been resulted in one of these two situation : a program encodes its content in whitespace, or a program written in [Whitespace (programming language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).

Comment: @JiminP, there's already a challenge for that. [Exploit "free whitespace"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3615/2180)

Comment: How does the bonus work if you have no mod, no div? then just 0.8?

Comment: Do "the 6th Fibonacci number", or "the 6th prime number" count as cop-outs here?

Comment: `Using some roundabout method of generating the number 13 for use is acceptable.` How do you determine what is "roundabout enough"?

Comment: @Cruncher This post is two years old. Rather than ask a ghost for clarification, why don't you just submit an edit to make it clearer?

Comment: @Rusher To be honest, I didn't notice that it was 2 years old, it just recently became active. As for your suggestion, I'd rather not ninja-change as non-OP a question with 2 pages of answers..

Comment: @Cruncher - I'd totally forgotten about it too but I kept getting notifications about it.  I had no idea it would suddenly become popular again.

Comment: @ajax333221 and JavaScript (26 chars) `function f(n){return "no"}`. This will return 'no' for all the numbers that can't be divided by 13

Comment: `var o="             "; if((input%(o.length))==0){return "yes"} else {return "no"}`

Answer (score 23):

### Java (score <strike>60.8</strike> 59.2)

```
void t(int n){System.out.print(Math.cos(.483321946706122*n)>.9?"yes":"no");}
```

Score: (76 - 2 whitespace) chars * 0.8 = 59.2

Comment: Ingenious.  I like it!

Comment: `println` -> `print`?

Comment: @Geobits, true.

Answer (score 19):

**ASM - 16 bit x86 on WinXP command shell**

executable - 55 bytes * 0.8 = 44

source - 288 characters * 0.8 = 230.4

The number 13 doesn't even appear in the assembled .com file.

Assemble using A86.

```
    mov si,82h
    xor ax,ax
    xor cx,cx
a:  imul cx,10
    add cx,ax
    lodsb
    sub al,48
    jnc a
    inc cx
h:  mov dl,a and 255
c:  loop g
    sub dl,a and 255
    jz e
    mov dl,4
e:  add dl,k and 255
    mov dh,1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    ret
g:  inc dl
    cmp dl,c and 255
    jne c
    jmp h
k:  db 'yes$no$'
```

Comment: I understand that this solution is clever, but seeing as this is code-golf, shouldn't we be upvoting shortest solutions rather than cleverest solutions?

Comment: @mellamokb: From what I've read on meta, some people think voting is a mark of appreciation for a clever / unusual solution. If we only voted on the shortest answer, there wouldn't be any point in having voting. I guess the 'tick' goes to the shortest code as a mark of ultimate kudos. Then again, a simple solution in golfscript will always be smaller than a really clever solution in C - so who deserves the votes? In the end, the votes aren't that important, it's about having fun.

Comment: rule: `The input will always be an integer greater than 0 and less than 2^32`. You can't use 16bit

Comment: @Fabricio: All 16bit numbers are less than 2^32. :-)

Comment: lol.. you're right somehow. But you can't handle 2^32-1 =p

Answer (score 18):

## Python 3.x: 54 * 0.8 = 43.2

It may be a cop-out to have a string of length 13, but here it goes:

```
print('no' if any((' ' * int(input())).split('             ')) else 'yes')
```

It works by building a string of n spaces (the choice of delimiter is arbitrary, but I chose space for obvious reasons), and splitting away 13-space substrings until you're left with a string containing n%13 spaces.

Comment: +1.  I like the split by 13 character whitespace.  Moving it to Python 2 and using a technique from my answer takes it down to score of 35.2: `print 'yneos'[any((' ' * input()).split('             '))::2]`

Comment: I was about to say: you could replace `'             '` with `'  '*6+' '` to save 5 chars - but then I found that spaces did not count at all...

Answer (score 14):

### GolfScript, 32 chars

```
~){.14base{+}*.@<}do('no''yes'if
```

I wanted to try something different from everyone else, so my solution calculates the base 14 [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of the number, by repeatedly converting the number to base **14** and summing the digits until the result no longer gets any smaller.  This is essentially the same as calculating the remainder modulo 13, except that the result will be in the range 1 to 13 instead of 0 to 12.

Since checking whether the digital root equals 13 would be difficult without using the number 13 itself (or some lame workaround like 12+1), what I actually do is I increment the input number by one before the loop and decrement the result afterwards.  That way, the result for numbers divisible by 13 will in fact be zero, which is much easier to check for.

Here's a commented version of the program:

```
~              # evaluate the input, turning it from a string to a number
)              # increment by one
{              # start of do-loop 
    .          # make a copy of the previous number, so we can tell when we're done
    14 base    # convert the number to base 14
    { + } *    # sum the digits
    . @ <      # check if the new number is less than the previous number...
} do           # ...and repeat the loop if so
(              # decrement the result by one
'no' 'yes' if  # output 'no' if the result is non-zero, 'yes' if it's zero
```

This program will actually handle *any* non-negative integer inputs, since GolfScript uses bignum arithmetic.  Of course, extremely large inputs may consume excessive time and/or memory.

The code does not use either modulos or division directly, although it does use GolfScipt's base conversion operator, which almost certainly does some division and remainder-taking internally.  I'll leave it for GigaWatt to decide whether this qualifies me for the bonus or not.

Comment: If only everyone would comment their golfscript code so well. Kudos

Answer (score 12):

### C, 68 * 0.8 = 54.4

After 24 answers, no one came up with this obvious algorithm yet:

```
f(x){puts("no\0yes"+3*((x*330382100LL>>32)-(~-x*330382100LL>>32)));}
```

Comment: I was waiting for someone to do an integer reciprocal multiply. Not only is it an elegant solution to the challenge, but it's a useful technique in it's own right as a performance optimization.

Comment: Is this still valid even though it's very non-standard?

Comment: @oldrinb, I see no requirement for standard compliance in the question. In general, strict standard compliance is awfully annoying in code golf.

Comment: Could you explain why this works?

Comment: @user2767189, it's a technique called "reciprocal multiply" - basically a way to implement division by X using multiplication by (2^K / X). In this case X is 13, and 330382100*13 is almost exactly 2^32.

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (27.9)

Current version (31 characters * 0.90 bonus = 27.9).

```
alert(prompt()*2%26?'no':'yes')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9GQ9m/2/

**Edit 1:** Forgo second bonus by using modulus to lower score considerably and avoid `for` loop.  Also eliminate `~~` and save two chars (thanks `@copy`).

---

Older version (48 characters * 0.80 bonus = 38.4)

```
for(n=~~prompt()*2;n-=26>0;);alert(n?'no':'yes')​
```

Comment: Multiply everything by two and use 26 instead... didn't see that coming.

Comment: You can omit the `~~` assuming valid input; otherwise `prompt()<<1` will work too.

Comment: Although I will admit it technically doesn't reach the limit of 2^32 anymore using this method..

Comment: In fact it does work beyond 2^32 since you dropped any bitwise operators now.

Comment: Might not be the highest score, but the most readable and clear

Comment: This is still using an arithmetic quickie to determine divisibility by 13, and there was a rule saying no arithmetic cop outs...

Comment: @WallyWest: We all had fun at the time.  Is it really necessary to downvote an answer that is over two years old?

Comment: @Mellamokb Sorry, got a little overzealous... Reverted

Answer (score 7):

### BrainFuck

Score: 200 * 0.8 = 160

```
>++++++[>++++++++<-]>>,[<[-<+>>-<]<[->+<]>>>[->++++++++++<]>[-<+>]<<[->+<],]++++
+++++++++>[>+<-<-[>>>]>>[[-<<+>>]>>>]<<<<]>[<<<[-<++>]<++++++++++++++.+.>]<<[[-<
++++++<++++++++>>]<-----.<---.>------.>]
```

Reads froms stdin. Probably not the most clever solution, but getting anything that works in BF is nice. It's quite compact though.

Comment: Any explanation on how it works?  It seems like by default BrainFuck would get the full 0.8 bonus because it simply doesn't have division or modulus.

Comment: @GigaWatt it calculates the modulus.

Comment: Aye, but what I meant was that it doesn't use the modulus operator (because it doesn't have one).  Therefore it'll always get the bonus for not using it.  Also, nice bio pic.

Comment: @GigaWatt I didn't disagree with you, just answered your question.

Answer (score 7):

**Scala (38 * 0.9 = 34.2)**

Similar to `0xD`(hex) or `015`(oct).

**ASCII** value of `CR` is 13.

```
def t(n:Int)=if(n%'\r'==0)"yes"else"no"
```

Comment: I wondered how long it'd be before I saw someone exploit ascii values.

Comment: Can you add the score to your post please?  Should be 38 * 0.9 = 34.2.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 28 * 0.8 = 22.4

```
f x|gcd 26x>2="yes"|1<3="no"
```

Answer (score 5):

Python:

```
f=lambda n:1==pow(8,n,79)
```

E.g.

```
[i for i in range(100) if f(i)]
```

gives

```
[0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91]
```

Comment: now this one I like. however there needs to be a yes/no according to the challenge criteria, and you should post your score (25*.08 = `20`)

Comment: `f=lambda n:pow(8,n,79)-1 and "no" or "yes"` fixes it, 43*0.8=34.4

Answer (score 4):

#### ECMAScript 6, 25 × 0.9 = 22.5

Yeah, it's a boring way of getting 13.

```
n => n % '             '.length ? 'no' : 'yes'
```

Comment: i was trying to figure out how your score was so low, then i realized the genius in using whitespace for your number... lol

Comment: +1 for abusing the rules. If I stated them, it would be "not counting REMOVABLE whitespace". So is anyone going to give us a 0 byte solution?

Comment: @ugoren [Wish granted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5003/53745)

Answer (score 4):

### C, 54.4 == 68 * .8   <strike>80 * .8</strike>

```
char*f(c){char*s=" yes\0\rno";while(c&&*s++);return c>0?f(c-*s):++s;}
```

Comment: Nice use of `\r` - I thought it's only good for Windows support. But why `c>0` when `c` would do?

Comment: @ugoren: it wouldn't do, think about it.

Comment: You're right, I got confused somehow. I was thinking about numbers above 2^31, where `>0` is no good. But instead of noticing that your function doesn't support them, I thought `==` is good.

Answer (score 3):

### APL ((21 - 1) × 0.8 = 16)

```
'yes' 'no'[1=⎕∨⌊⍟9*6]
```

`⎕IO` should be set to 0 for this to work properly in Dyalog APL. To generate 13, we take the floor (`⌊`) of the natural logarithm (`⍟`) of 9 to the power of 6 (`9*6`). After that, we find the GCD (`∨`) of our input (`⎕`) and 13, and we then test if that equals 1. This is used to index (`[...]`) the vector of answers.

If anyone wants to be pedantic about the mention of *bytes* in the scoring specification, the score for the UTF-8 encoded version of this is `(29 - 1) × 0.8 = 22.4`. :)

Comment: I *so* want to be pedantic about bytes.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh **snap** you di-_int_.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 88

Fibonacci trick.

```
f(n){return n<2?n:f(n-1)+f(n-2);}main(x){printf("%s",x%f(7)?"No":"Yes",scanf("%d",&x));}
```

Comment: You're using 13 via f(7)... That's kinda bending the rules a bit...

Answer (score 3):

### Perl - 44 × 0.8 = 35.2

```perl
#!perl -p
map$_+=4*chop,($_)x10;$_=chop^$_*3?'no':yes
```

Counting the shebang as one byte.

I'm a bit late to the game, but I thought I'd share the algorithm, as no other posts to this point have used it.

This works under the observation that if *n* is divisible by *13*, then ⌊*n/10*⌋+*n%10*4* is also divisible by *13*. The values *13*, *26* and *39* cycle onto themselves. All other multiples of *13* will eventually reach one of these values in no more than *log<sub>10</sub> n* iterations.

---

**In Other Bases**

Admittedly, `chop` is a bit of a cop-out. With a base 10 representation, it's equivalent to `divmod`. But the algorithm works prefectly well in other bases, for example base 4, or 8.

Python style pseudo-code of the above algorithm (base 10):

```python
def div13(n):
    while n > 40:
        q, r = n // 10, n % 10
        n = q + 4*r
    return n in [13, 26, 39]
```

In base 2:

```python
def div13(n):
    while n > 40:
        q, r = n >> 1, n & 1
        n = q + 7*r
    return n in [13, 26, 39]
```

In base 4:

```python
def div13(n):
    while n > 40:
        q, r = n >> 2, n & 3
        n = q + 10*r
    return n in [13, 26, 39]
```

In base 8:

```python
def div13(n):
    while n > 40:
        q, r = n >> 3, n & 7
        n = q + 5*r
    return n in [13, 26, 39]
```

etc. Any base smaller than 13 works equally well.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript: 59*0.8 = 47.2 (?)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9aeCU/2/):

```
function r(n){
  for(c=0;n>c;n-=12,c++);
  return n==c?'yes':'no';
}
```

---

Including mellamokb's improvement (57*0.8 = 45.6):

```
function r(n){
  for(c=0;n>c;n-=12,c++);
  return n-c?'no':'yes'
}
```

Comment: You can save two chars by changing return to `return n-c?'no':'yes'` and omitting the second semicolon.

Comment: @mellamokb Good catch. Could probably improve further by writing it in Ruby, or something that allows more compact function definitions.

Comment: There is also an accepted standard on CG to use `prompt` for input and `alert` for output, which makes the program interactive and saves a few chars.

Answer (score 2):

**Perl: (51-4 spaces)*0.9 = 42.3**

```
say+<>%(scalar reverse int 40*atan2 1,1)?'no':'yes'
```

> 40*atan2(1,1) -> 31.41592 (PI*10)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl (19.8)

21 bytes * .9

```
say2*<>%26?"no":"yes"
```

*note:* My first Perl program ever.  Weakly typed is good for golf i guess.

Comment: I've found that a good way to measure your knowledge of a language is to try and golf in it.  Usually requires knowing edge cases.
Also, your score is actually 23 * 0.90 (whitespace doesn't count).

Comment: Thought I had accounted for the whitespace.  Fixed now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Wow.  No love for Perl.  Can't say I like it either.

Answer (score 2):

**in C (K&R): 47 * 0.8 = 37.6**

```
f(i){for(;i>0;i-=__LINE__);puts(i?"no":"yes");}
```

EDIT1: okay removed all dependencies on external functions, the above will work as long as you put this line on the 13th line of the file! :) If `__LINE__` is okay to be replaced by say `0xd` then can save a further 5 characters (score: 33.6)

Comment: If this needs to be on 13th line, you need to add 12 newlines to your code, and therefore, to your score: it becomes 59 * 0.8 = 47.2

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby (<strike>50</strike> 48 * 0.9 = 43.2)

Smart way to use `eval`

```
eval x="p gets.to_i*3%x.length == 0? 'yes':'no'"
```

Answer (score 2):

### J - 22.4 <sup>= 28 * 0.8</sup>

Based on [mxmul's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2289/mxmul) clever [cyclic method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4956/46).

```
f=:<:{('yes',~12 3$'no ')$~]
```

Examples:

```
   f 13
yes
   f 23
no
   f 13*513
yes
   f 123456789
no
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (108 less 0 for whitespace) => 108, x 0.8 (no modulus, no division) = 86.4

`b=b=>{a=z,a=a+"";return+a.slice(0,-1)+4*+a.slice(-1)};z=prompt();for(i=99;i--;)z=b();alert(b()-z?"no":"yes")`

This method uses the following algorithm:
 1. Take the last digit, multiply it by four, add it to the rest of
 the truncated number.
 2. Repeat step 1 for 99 iterations...
 3. Test it one more time using step 1, if the resulting number is itself, you've found a multiple of 13.

Previous update, removed `var`, and reversed logic at the alert to remove more chars by using subtraction-false conditional.

Technically, the end result is that you'll eventually reach a two digit number like 13, 26, or 39 which when run through step 1 again will give 13, 26, or 39 respectively. So testing for iteration 100 being the same will confirm the divisibility.

Answer (score 2):

## Cheddar, 20 bytes (noncompeting)

#### Score is 20 * 0.9 = 18

```
n->n*2%26?'no':'yes'
```

A straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp (71 bytes * 0.8) = 56.8

Simple recursion, really.

`(defun w(x)(if(> x 14)(w(- x 13))(if(> 14 x 12)(print'yes)(print'no))))`

Ungolfed:

```
(defun w (x)
  (if (> x 14)
      (w (- x 13))
      (if (> 14 x 12)
          (print 'yes)
          (print 'no))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### D 56 chars .80 bonus = 44.8

```
bool d(double i){
    return modf(i*0,0769230769,i)<1e-3;
}
```

this might have been a cop-out with using 1/13 and a double can store any 32 bit number exactly

edit: this works by multiplying with 1/13 and checking the fractional part if it's different from 0 (allowing for rounding errors) or in other words it check the fractional part of i/13

Comment: doesn't modf count as using modulus?

Comment: @Blazer not really it takes the fractional part of the first argument and returns it while storing the integral part in the second arg

Comment: Just a note: the result (yes/no) has to actually be output.  Also, I'm somewhat curious as how this solution works.  An explanation would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7

(20 - 1 whitespace) * 0.9 (no division) = **17.1**

```
print input()%015==0
```

yes/no instead of true/false: 31 * 0.9 (no division) = **27.9**

```
print'yneos'[input()%015!=0::2]
```

takes advantage of python's `int` to convert other bases from strings into base 10 integers. you can see in both versions they use a different (yet same character length) base

edit: 1 char save in yes/no version

edit2: another 2 chars shaved!

edit3: thanks again to comments! even more characters shaved off by using python's builtin octal representations (`015` == `13`...) instead of int's base translation

Comment: I see a cop-out with the different bases

Comment: 14 in base 9?  I should have seen that coming.

Comment: `print['no','yes'][input()%int('d',14)==0`

Comment: as far as I saw, a cop-out was defined as being something like `14-1` or `26/2`. I just took creative liberty to represent 13

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks for the 1 char save :P

Comment: `print'yneos'[input()%int('d',14)==0`

Comment: I do think this fails the rule "No cop-out synonyms for 13 either (like using 15 - 2)".

Comment: Forgot a closing bracket 2 comments ago:  `print'yneos'[input()%int('d',14)==0]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you also forgot that it can't be `==0` otherwise it will say 'yes' for numbers not divisible by 13 and 'no' for numbers that are, and `::2` for the step. but I fixed it nonetheless :P

Comment: @Blazer.  Sheesh, I'm full of errors.  At least I got it right in my answer.

Comment: we'll let @GigaWatt decide whether the base cop-out counts as a violation of the rules or not

Comment: @Blazer:  If `int('14',9)` is acceptable, you may as well shorten it to `015`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski how does that work exactly? edit: nvm I see now that it's octal conversion

Comment: I would consider base conversions as bending the rules considerably, but because I wasn't specific enough to begin with, I'll have to let it slide.  I'd prefer to see something a bit more clever than a round-about creation of 13, but as it stands, your entry is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - score 27.9

**(31 characters * 0.90)** -- forgoes some bonus for shorter code.

```
print'yneos'[2*input()%26>0::2]
```

**older version:** (47 characters * 0.80) -- complete rip-off of mellamokb's Javascript answer, but in Python.

```
n=2*input()
while n>0:n-=26
print'yneos'[n<0::2]
```

**older version:** (60 characters * 0.80)

```
n=input()
while n>12:
 for _ in'x'*12+'!':n-=1
print'yneos'[n>0::2]
```

**older version:** (105 characters * 0.80)

```
n=abs(input())
while n>12:n=abs(sum(int(x)*y for x,y in zip(`n`[::-1],n*(1,-3,-4,-1,3,4))))
print'yneos'[n>0::2]
```

Comment: Hmm, this is a nifty method.  That 1,-3,-4 pattern is similar to what I saw on wikipedia.  Still cool to see it in code.

Comment: @GigaWatt:  That's where I got it.  The other pattern `(1,10,9,12,3,4)` would save 1 character but would not resolve to a value less than 13.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 95 * 0.8 = 76

```
$_=<>;
while($_>0){
$q=7*chop;
$d=3*($m=chop$q);
chop$d;
$_-=$d+$m}
if($_){print"no"}
else{print"yes"}
```

The line breaks were added for clarity. I could have probably made this answer a lot shorter, but I feel that this answer represents a unique way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### In Q:

```
d:{$[0=x mod "I"$((string 6h$"q")[1 2]);`yes;`no]}
50*.9=45
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE. You should put your code in a codeblock, and which point you can *use* backticks where you mean backticks as they no longer have formatting meaning. I've done the first part for you, please check it and fix any errata I've introduced.

Answer (score 1):

## **Right Linear Grammar - ∞ points**

```
S->ε
S->1A
S->0S
S->9I
S->3C
S->5E
S->4D
S->2B
S->7G
S->6F
S->8H
F->3K
K->0F
A->2L
K->1G
A->5B
A->0J
B->7A
J->5A
G->6K
G->8S
H->9K
F->5S
K->2H
I->6E
I->5D
J->4S
D->8I
B->6S
K->9B
F->6A
G->9A
K->6L
K->4J
C->1E
L->8K
E->5C
B->4K
C->0D
J->2K
D->2C
A->9F
J->7C
C->6J
C->8L
E->0K
L->0C
B->9C
E->2S
L->6I
I->0L
J->0I
B->2I
I->3B
H->1C
I->7F
C->4H
F->1I
G->4I
I->0G
C->3G
F->8C
D->0A
E->3A
I->9H
A->7D
C->2F
H->7I
A->8E
F->9D
E->8F
A->6C
D->6G
G->0E
D->5F
E->9G
H->2D
D->7H
H->3E
I->2A
K->3I
C->9S
C->7K
E->4B
D->1B
L->1D
J->9E
I->1S
E->1L
J->8D
D->9J
L->2E
J->3L
B->5L
B->8B
L->7J
L->9L
G->1F
A->4A
K->5K
B->3J
H->6H
E->7E
J->1J
D->4E
G->2G
J->6B
D->3D
E->6D
H->4F
I->4C
C->5I
F->0H
H->5G
K->7S
G->3H
L->5H
H->8J
A->3S
H->0B
B->1H
G->7L
K->8A
F->2J
F->7B
L->4G
F->4L
A->1K
B->0G
G->5J
L->3F
```

Then depending on how you choose to 'run' it, it will output 'yes' or 'no'.

Not a serious entry, just some fun ;)

**EDIT:**
Perhaps I should explain a bit.

A [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) is a set of rules (productions) which define a [language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language). A language can be thought of as all of the possible strings formed by an alphabet, that conform to the rules of it's grammar.

Here the alphabet is the set of all decimal digits. The grammar's rules are that all strings must form decimal integers that are divisible by 13.

We can use the grammar above to test whether a string belongs to our language.

The rules of the grammar contain terminal symbols (which are elements in the language) as well as non-terminal symbols which are replaced recursively.

It's easier to explain what's going on with an example:

Lets say for example that the string we are testing is 71955.

There is always a start symbol (which is non-terminal), in the case of the grammar above this is 'S'. At this point we have not read any characters from our string:

```
current pattern                    symbol read
S                                  ε
```

Now, we read the first symbol in our string which is '7', then we look for a rule in the grammar which has any of the non-terminals in our current pattern in the left hand side of the '->' and that has our symbol in the right hand side of the '->'.
Luckily there is one (S->7G), so we replace the non-terminal symbols in our current pattern with the right hand side of the new rule:

```
current pattern                    symbol read
7G                                 7
```

Now we have the non-terminal 'G' in our pattern, and the next symbol to be read is '1', So we look for a rule in our grammar that begins with 'G->1". We find there is one (G->1F), so we replace the non terminal with the RHS of our new rule:

```
current pattern                    symbol read
71F                                1
```

Keep repeating this process:

Next rule: F->9D

```
current pattern                    symbol read
719D                               9
```

Next rule: D->5F

```
current pattern                    symbol read
7195F                              5
```

Next rule: F->5S

```
current pattern                    symbol read
71955S                             5
```

At this point we have no more symbols in our string, but we have another non-terminal symbol in there. We see from the first rule in the grammar that we can replace 'S' with the empty string (ε): S->ε

Doing so gives us the current patter: 71955ε which is the equivalent to 71955.

We have read all of the symbols in our string, and the pattern contains no non-terminal symbols. Which means that the string belongs to the language and therefore 71955 is in fact divisible by 13.

I.e. the goal is to have pattern = string.
If you are left with any non-terminal symbols, after reading all of the symbols in your string, the string doesnt belong to the language. Likewise, if you still have more symbols in your string to read, but there are no rules in the grammar allowing you to go forward, then the string does not belong to the language.

Comment: I'm... not even sure what I'm looking at here.

Comment: @GigaWatt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar :)

Answer (score 1):

49 characters in Burlesque: `0\/r@{1\/.-<-12\/.-<-}{L[1.>}w!L[{"no" "yes"}\/!!` (assuming the number to check is already on the stack. see [here](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=39%200%5C%2Fr%40%7B1%5C%2F.-%3C-12%5C%2F.-%3C-%7D%7BL%5B1.%3E%7Dw!L%5B%7B%22no%22%20%22yes%22%7D%5C%2F!!) in action.)

Does not use division, does not use modulo. It actually does not use any arithmetic at all... just list manipulation.

Comment: 48. The whitespace between "no" and "yes" is optional. If input comes from stdin and output is expected on stdout prepend `ps` and append `sh` leading to 52 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 26*.9 ==23.4

```
If[2 n~Mod~26 == 0, "yes", "no"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi XE3 114*0.8 = 91.2

```
function d(n:integer):string;var i:int8;begin d:='No';while n>0do for I:=0to 5do n:=n-2;if n=0then exit('Yes')end;
```

#### Ungolfed

```
function d(n:integer):string;
var
  i:int8;
begin
  d:='No';
  while n>0do
    for I:=0to 5do
      n:=n-2;
  if n=0then exit('Yes')
end;
```

Does not use division, does not use mod, does not contain the number 13

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2: 33 * 0.9 = 29.7 points

```
print['yes','no'][input()*2%26>0]
```

`n*2%26` is equivalent to `n%13`. `input()*2%26` will give a number from 0 to 12, and only numbers with 0 should print `yes`. To solve that, we add `>0`. `0>0 == False` but `all(map(lambda n:n>0,range(1, 13))) == True`. `False` gets implicitly converted to `0`, and `True` to `1`, and the string in the appropriate index is printed.

Answer (score 1):

## Python2.7, 57B

```
x=input()
while x>50:x=x//10+x%10*4
print x==x//10+x%10*4
```

No *2%26 <s>bullshit</s> trickery here. I think it would be more interesting if all non-zero multiples of 13 were forbidden.

Alternative (per wikipedia) algorithm in slightly more interesting code in 77B:

```
print not(sum([int(s)*[1,-3,-4,-1,3,4][i%6]for i,s in enumerate(`x`[::-1])]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**C#** 98 chars (score 98*.80 = 76.8)

Shorter version:

```
int l="ThisIsLongNo?".Length;while(i>0)i-=l;if(i==0)Console.Write("yes");else Console.Write("no");
```

Easy to read version:

```
int length = "ThisIsLongNo?".Length;
while (input > 0)
    input -= length;
if (input == 0)
    Console.Write("yes");
else
    Console.Write("no");
```

Comment: This takes a ridiculously long time for input `4294967287`.

Comment: Use inline if `?:` to save a few chars.

Answer (score 1):

## BASH, 57.6 (72*0.8) <strike>58.4</strike>

The x file:

```
set - `factor $1` 17
shift
while(($1<12))
do
    shift
done
(($1>16)) && echo no || echo yes
```

The size:

```
$ cat x | tr -d ' \t\n' | wc -c
72
```

The run:

```
$ for i in 1 12 13 14 142 143 144 4294967295; do echo $i - $(bash x $i) ; done
1 - no
12 - no
13 - yes
14 - no
142 - no
143 - yes
144 - no
4294967295 - no
```

Comment: Nice idea, if you use backticks instead of `$( ... )` you have one char less.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP ~84 characters.
`$n=26;// e.g.
function m($n){$x=ord(4)/4;while($n>=$x){$n-=$x;}return $n|0;}echo m($n)?'no':'yes';`

I actually prefer this method for getting 13 though (below in function form):

`function a(){
    return (int)((int)true.floor(pi()));
}`

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, ES6, 74.4

Program **106*.8 = 84.8**:

```
alert((f=n=>(n=n.toString(14).split("").reduce((r,x)=>+("0x"+x)+r,0))<14?n>12?"yes":"no":f(n))(+prompt()))
```

Function **93*.8 = 74.4**:

```
f=n=>(n=n.toString(14).split("").reduce((r,x)=>+("0x"+x)+r,0))<14?alert(n>12?"yes":"no"):f(n)
```

The number in base 14 is divisible by 13 if and only if sum of its digits is divisible by 13.
Repeat summing digits until number will be 1 digit in base 14.
The answer is "yes" when this number is 13 or 0.
We can ignore 0 as it can be in result only when initial number is 0 (which is out of range by the rules), so it have to be greater than 12.

No explicit divisions and modulus, no any whitespaces, also no 13 in any form.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 27 non-whitespace bytes * 0.9 = 24.3

```
"_v#%\*4"#&<@,,<"no
  >"sey",      ^
```

Multiplies the input by 4, then checks whether the result is divisible by 52. The 4 and the 52 both come from the `4` literal in the code, which is used for its ASCII value of 52 when read from left to right, then as the number 4 when read from right to left after the `<` reverses direction.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 34x0.8 = 27.2

```
p gets.to_i.gcd(0xD)==0?"yes":"no"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ocaml**

```
let p n =
   if ((n>0) &&(n mod (40 mod 27)) = 0) then "yes" else "no"
```

13 = x+13 mod x.

Comment: Why `*0.8`? You're blatantly using `mod`.

Comment: I didn't get it right, my bad

Comment: Still not quite right: you get a multiplier of 0.9 for using mod but not div.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, Score <s>73</s> 68*0.8=<s>58.4</s> 54.4

```
for(i=prompt();(i=(i&15)+3*(i>>4))>16;);alert(((i+3)&15)?"no":"yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

99 * 0.9 = 89,1 
(Used division but no mod)

```
var = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine())* 2 / 26;
if (s == (int)s) Console.Write("Yes");
else Console.Write("No");
```

This is in C#. Probably not a very good language to golf in. Feel free to improve it in different languages (or in c#) aslong as the method is the same.

Comment: I think you meant `var s` at the beginning. Also, try to get rid of useless whitespace (ex: `*2/26` instead of `* 2 / 26`)

Comment: the last two lines can be rewritten as `Console.Write(s==(int)s?"Yes":"No")`

Answer (score 0):

PYTHON 2.6

Now, this is not the shortest code, but the idea should be very easy to comprehend. Does not work with n = 0 but that can be fixed with `if not n or s[-2:] == '.5' or '.' not in s`.

```
def foo(n):
    s = str(n/26.0)
    return 'yes' if s[-2:] == '.5' or '.' not in s else 'no'
```

Answer (score 0):

## C Language

```
include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
int number = 45;
int i=0;

while(number >=12)
{
for(i=0;i<=12;i++)
    number -=1;
}

if (number==0)
  printf("Divisible");
else
  printf("Not Divisible");
}
```

Comment: Hi Sim. Welcome to code golf!  The idea behind Code-Golf challenges is to write as short of code as possible that solves the problem.  This is done by using shorter variable names like `n` instead of `number`, or by cleverly combining loops or code sequences together.  Also, the spec is defined to be 100% objective and ambiguous.  You'll notice, for example, that the spec defines the output as `yes` or `no`.  Please conform to the spec with your code and identify your score in the header to your post.  Thanks, and welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic - 164 CHARS

```
i = 9
s = 0
WHILE s < i
        s=s+NOT-14
        IF s=i THEN
                ? "YES"
        ELSEIF s > i THEN
                ? "NO"
        END IF
WEND
```

Set i to the number you want to test. Will Print Y if divisible by 13, otherwise, will print no. Updated to not use simple addition for to generate 13. Actual Non-Whitespace Characters is 66.  No Division. No Modulus.

### SCORE 53.49

Comment: Have you tested this for numbers larger than 13?  It would appear that it would print out YES/NO many times.. I think you want your output to occur after the WEND.  Also, you should be able to golf the output more using something like `? MID$("NO YES", (s=i)*3+1,3)`

Comment: works fine for numbers larger than 13. Will only print yes or no when it reaches the number, or if it finds that it goes past the number.  After this, the loop exits.

Comment: Ah. I missed `ELSEIF s > i`.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 108 x 0.8 = 86.4

```
def F(n):s=oct(n);return F(abs(sum(int(s[-1-i])*[1,-5,-1,5][i&3]for i in range(len(s)))))if n>7 else'yneos'[n>0::2]
```

Not going to win, but does an interesting trick by iterating over the octal digits of the number and reducing them modulo 13 (e.g. the "hundreds" digit is multiplied by -1 since 8^2==12==-1 mod 13).

Answer (score 0):

## Q, 30 * 0.9 = 27

```
{$[0=x mod "i"$"\r";`yes;`no]}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, score: <del>25.6</del> 24.8

OK, my program abuses perl's **regex engine**. It's a little bit obfuscated to look funnier.

```
say+(q x x x <>)=~m ?^(\?:             )+$??"yes":"no"
```

A shorter and "more readable" version would look like this:

```
say+(" "x<>)=~/^(             )+$/?"yes":"no"
```

I'm not quite sure how to count this. I ignore whitespace, so it goes down to these <del>32</del> 31 countable characters:

```
say+(""x<>)=~/^()+$/?"yes":"no"
```

which of course doesn't work, but the rules are like that. Because there's no modulus or division, I use factor *0.8*. Please correct me if I'm wrong here. :)

Answer (score 0):

## perl, 228.8 (286 chars)

This solution is long, but it's fun. It contains no cheapo, oddball representation of 13 whatsoever. It doesn't use division or modulus. It works on any integer of any length and runs in - O(log²n) time.

In all its glory:

```
@x=(1,10,9,12,3,4);sub a{$a=shift;$b=0;$c=0;for(0..length($a)-1){$c=0 if$c==6;$b+=$x[$c++]*substr$a,length($a)-$_-1,1}$b}sub b{my$c;$d=shift;do{$c=$d;$d=a$c}while($d!=$c);$x[1]=-3;$e=a$c;$x[1]=10;abs$e}sub c{@d=split//,sprintf"%02d",b$_[0];$d[0]*3==$d[1]}$\=$/;print c(abs<>)?"yes":"no"
```

Oh wait, was this not an obfuscation contest? Oops =)

Anyway, here's how it works: First, we note that the ones digit is the same modulo 13 as the millions digit, and the tens digit is the same modulo 13 as the ten millions, etc. This yields the sequence (1,10,9,12,3,4). So, we sum (sequence[digit_number % 6])*digit_value. That gives us a smaller number that is the same modulo 13 as our input. We keep doing this until we fail to get a smaller number. Any number that fails to get smaller must be in the range 0-99. So now we take that number and feed it in to the same algorithm after changing the value for the tens digit from 10 to -3 (which is the same modulo 13). This yields a number in the range -27 to 9. If a number is a multiple of -13, it is a multiple of 13 as well, so we return the absolute value, yielding a number in the range 0-27. The multiples of 13 in the 0..27 range are 0, 13, and 26. 13 and 26 have the property that the tens digit * 3 == the ones digit. If 0 is represented as 00, it has this property as well. No other number in the range 0..27 has this property. Thus, we've determined if the input number is a multiple of 13 or not.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript: 74*0.8 = 59.2

```javascript
function a(b){alert(eval(String.fromCharCode(98,37,49,51))==0?'Yes':'No')}
```

Try it out [here](http://js.do/code/36475)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, Score: 64 - 20% = 51.2

```
$a=$argv[0];while($b-$i<$a){$b+=14;$i++;}echo($b-$i==$a?yes:no);
```

14 is added to `$b` in every cycle, and then it check if `$b-$i` (where `$i` is the n° of cycles) is greater of equal the input number. If it is equal, it is a multiple of 13, otherwise it's not.

Answer (score 0):

## Python- 38 chars

I hope this doesn't count as a cop-out, but here it goes:

```
print["no","yes"][input()%ord("\x0D")==0]
```

Explanation:

```
                          ord("\x0D")       ---i.e. 13
                  input()%ord("\x0D")==0    ---the divisibility check
     ["no","yes"][input()%ord("\x0D")==0]   ---the bool we get is used as an index
print["no","yes"][input()%ord("\x0D")==0]   ---and we print the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 30*0.9=27

```
f(x) = x%endof("            ")==0?"yes":"no"
```

Comment: SE's markdown interpreter strips consecutive spaces. You can get around it by putting your code inside a code block, which also makes it a nice monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell: 65.6

Characters: 82
Multiplier: 0.8 (No modulus or division.)
Total: 65.6

**Golfed Code**

```
for($y=read-host;$x-lt$y;$x+='StackExchange'.length){}if($x-eq$y){"yes"}else{"no"}
```

**Un-Golfed & Commented**

```
# Set up a for loop to add 13 (derived from the length of a string) to an initially null variable ($x) until it meets or exceeds a user-input value ($y).
for($y=read-host;$x-lt$y;$x+='StackExchange'.length){}

# After for loop exits, check final value of $x against $y.
# If values match, $y is divisible by 13.
if($x-eq$y){"yes"}else{"no"}
```

If you're going to use a string length to get to 13, you may as well make the string interesting.

(May take a long time for very large values of $y.)

Answer (score 0):

### Pure Bash 40=50*0.8

File `x`:

```
j=$1*2
while ((j>0))
do
((j-=26))
done && echo no || echo yes
```

Use as, e.g., `bash x 13` or `bash x 14`. Character count:

```
$ tr -d '[:space:]' < x | wc -c
50
```

---

Older was:

File `x`:

```
for ((j=$1*2;j>0;j-=26))
do
:
done
((j)) && echo no || echo yes
```

Use as, e.g., `bash x 13` or `bash x 14`. Character count:

```
$ tr -d '[:space:]' < x | wc -c
52
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 74 * 0.8 = 59.2

```cs
void f(int n)
{
    while (n >= 14)
        n = (n >> 1) + 7 * (n & 1);

    Console.Write(n <= 12 ? "no" : "yes");
}
```

**Explanation**

Write *n* as *n = 2 a + b*, i.e. *a = n / 2 = (n >> 1)* and *b = n % 2 = (n & 1)*

```
n          = 0    (mod 13)
2 a + b    = 0    (mod 13)
14 a + 7 b = 0    (mod 13)
a + 7 b    = 0    (mod 13)
```

So *n* is divisible by 13 if (and only if) *a + 7 b* is. Replace *n* by *a + 7 b*. Keep doing this until *n* is smaller than 14. *n* is now 13 if the starting value was divisble by 13 else *n* is some positive number smaller than 13.

Answer (score 0):

## ~-~! - 38 * 0.9 (no modulus) = 34.2

```
'=~~~~,~~~+~:''=|*/','==*[|yes|]|no||:
```

~-~! only supports integer division - thus, `*/','` (`x/13*13`)is equivalent to `*-*;'` (`x-x%13`). This checks whether `x/13*13 == x` and returns the appropriate string (yeah, it's a function, decimal console input is a huge pain)

Answer (score 0):

## k2, 22 char * 0.8 = 17.6

Just as you can sum the digits of a base 10 number to tell if it is divisible by 9, so too can you tell if a number is divisible by 13 if repeatedly summing its digits gives 13. As a function returning a string:

```
$`no`yes@12<(+/14_vs)/
```

`14_vs` expands the input into base 14, and then `+/` sums up the "digits". Wrapping that up into `(...)/` repeats the process until it produces no change, that is, the result is less than 14. then we simply check whether our result is greater than 12 with `12<`, and select the string "yes" or "no" (`` $`no`yes@ ``) based on that result.

```
  $`no`yes@12<(+/14_vs)/ 39
"yes"
  f:$`no`yes@12<(+/14_vs)/
  f 38
"no"
  f' 167 168 169 170 171
("no"
 "no"
 "yes"
 "no"
 "no")
  f 0
"no"
```

0 gives a "no" under this algorithm, but that's okay because the input is always greater than 0, according to the question. If we had to fix that, we would want to increment the number before and check for equality to 1, getting the **23 character** `` $`no`yes@1=(+/14_vs)/1+ ``.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 43.2

```
param($a)if((1.2307692307*$a)-band15){"no";exit}"yes"
```

Ungolfed

```
param($a)
if((1.2307692307 * $a) -band 15) {"no";exit}
"yes"
```

Magic number is of course 16/13. Multiplies by this, checks if the last four bits are all zero.

Answer (score 0):

### [GAP](http://gap-system.org), 45 bytes * 0.8 = 36

Instead of giving one more solution that computes `Gcd(26,n)`, I multiply with the one of the field with 169 elements (which has characteristic 13) and get zero iff n is divisible by 13. If I wanted a truthy result, I could just use `IsZero`, but to get a yes/no-String I turn that result into an ordinary integer, compute 0 to that power, add one and use that as index to a string list. Normally I could say `list[index]`, but that doesn't work with list literals. However there is another short way:

```
n->\[\](["no","yes"],1+0^Int(n*One(GF(169))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge, 121 bytes * 0.8 = 96.8

```
&:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-:!#v_1-       #
yes"<      >      >      >      >      >      >      >      >      >      >      >      >"on",,@,,,"
```

Uses the wraparound nature of Befunge's code--the top row repeatedly decrements the input number until reaching 0. When it reaches 0, it takes the next `v` down to the bottom row, where it either hits the one `<` or one of the twelve `>`s. The bottom row outputs "yes" if executed from right to left, and "no" from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 113 Bytes

```
var input = document.querySelector("input").value;if(input/parseInt(atob("MTM=")) != 0) {alert(0);}else{alert(1)}
```

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input").value;
if(input/parseInt(atob("MTM=")) != 0) {alert(0);}else{alert(1)}
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 79 Bytes

```
f=function(n)ifelse(any(1:n*as.integer(IQR(rnorm(100000,,10)))==n),"yes","no")
```

Relies on the interquartile range of a standard normal being a bit higher than 13.

ungolfed

```
f=function(n) {
    number=as.integer(IQR(rnorm(10000,,10)))
    seq=1:n*number
    if (any(seq==n)) {
        return("yes") 
    } else {return("no")}
}
```