# Shortest python3 code for: Find the difference between a number and a power of two not exceeding a given number

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

So, this is a task from one very popular educational site in Russia:
https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=786&ins=1

Mathematically, you need to find the power of two not exceeding the given number, read from the standard input stream, and output their difference in the standard output stream.
My **python3** solution takes **41** characters, but the leader’s solution is only **40** characters.
Who can shorten the code?

**Newlines, spaces and tabs are not included while counting code length.**

```
x = int(input())
print(x - 2 ** (len(bin(x)) - 3))
```

Comment: Your code (with spaces removed) is [42 characters](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIxK3QNdLS0shJzdNIyszTqNDU1DXW1Pz/39ACAA). Did you forget to count the newline, perhaps?

Comment: @Dingus spaces, tabs and newlines are not included.

Comment: You should state that in the question. Not counting spaces/tabs/newlines is unusual on this site.

Comment: It is almost certainly a bad idea not to count newlines, spaces and tabs because somebody can encode a binary string using spaces and tabs, decode it to ASCII and evaluate it.

Comment: The site states "[Размер кода] = max([длина кода без пробелов, табуляций и символов переноса], [полная длина кода, делённая нацело на 4])" - (I think this is something like...) code size is the greatest of (a) the code length without spaces, tabs and hyphens and (b) total code length divided by 4. Doesn't that make yours 39 (two hyphens, `-`)?

Comment: [Not counting whitespace in the score is not a good idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3615/46076). That said, the task here is so simple that the naive approach appears to be shorter than any of the answers to that question, so I won't close as duplicate.

Comment: @pppery Also, you shouldn't close as a duplicate, because that's a completely different challenge to this, where the only similarity is not counting whitespace

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The issue is that if you don't count whitespace there is a simple wrapper that solves any task in python in ~45 bytes of non-whitespace.  Thus it doesn't matter what the task is the the score is always the same assuming that you can solve the problem.  I agree with pppery here though that because this task is so simple that the wrapper method is not viable and thus this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes (not counting the newline)

First I simplified \$2^{a-3}\$ to \$\frac{2^a}8\$, then I used the lower-precedence operators `<<` and `^` so that `//` can be replaced by `-` (which saves a byte).

```python
x=int(input())
print(1<<len(bin(x))-3^x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIxDW0sclJzdNIyszTqNDU1DWOq9D8/9/MHAA)

Comment: If Python 2 is allowed, this can be [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AIyFWo0DXS0spJzdNIyszTqNDU1Lf4/9/MHAA) (not counting the space or newline).

Comment: @Dingus I think the `int(...)` is also not necessary in Python 2.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like you're right. (I don't know Python well enough to say for sure.)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate any idea to get 38?)))

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
print(int('0'+bin(int(input()))[3:],2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EA4TVDdS1kzLzNCD8gtISDU1NzWhjq1gdI03N//@NAA)

Subtracting the largest power of two less than a number is the same as removing the first `1` from its binary representation.

Unfortunately python rather mysteriously errors on trying to convert the empty binary string to an int so we need `'0'+` if we want it to work on zero or one.  If we relax the requirements to only require two or more then we can remove 4 bytes.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
print(int(bin(int(input()))[3:],2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EA4STMvM0IOyC0hINTU3NaGOrWB0jTc3//40A)

Comment: The question doesn't specify the version of Python to be used so you could switch to 2 and drop the inner `int()`.

Comment: @Shaggy ACMP only supports Python 3 (as far as I know).

Comment: @Ad Hoc Garf Hunter, Great!

Comment: "we need `'0'+` if we want it to work on zero or one" - `0` is an invalid input anyway, since it's smaller than all powers of 2.